# flask sqlalchemy error binding parameter 1 probably unsupported type

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

got this error  while executing my aap.py...cna anyone help?`

sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError: (sqlite3.InterfaceError) Error binding parameter 1 - probably unsupported type.
[SQL: INSERT INTO room (r_name, created_at, created_by, r_description) VALUES (?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('hello', <Users 13>, None)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)

> **my module.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy import DateTime
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///C:/sqlite3/database/chat.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)
manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)


class Users(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    phone_no = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True, nullable=False)
    city = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)
    rooms = db.relationship('Room', backref='users')


class Room(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    r_name = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=False, nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.current_timestamp())
    created_by = db.Column(db.String(200), db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
    r_description = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
    db.create_all()
```

'''

**my app.py**
'''

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from models import db, Users, Room, app
from datetime import datetime


@app.route('/user', methods=['POST'])
def add_users():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.json['name']
        email = request.json['email']
        phone_no = request.json['phone_no']
        city = request.json['city']

        new_user = Users(name=name, email=email, phone_no=phone_no, city=city)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        room = Room(r_name='hello')
        room.created_by = new_user
        # room.created_at = datetime(2015, 6, 5, 8, 10, 10, 10)
        db.session.add(room)
        db.session.commit()
        return jsonify({'message': 'successfully created user'})


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

`room.created_by` is an integer column, so you can't assign a `User` instance like `new_user` to it.

You could assign `new_user.id`

```
room.created_by = new_user.id
```

but it might be more elegant to make use of the `rooms` relationship defined on `User`.

This ought to work

```py
@app.route('/user', methods=['POST'])
def add_users():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.json['name']
        email = request.json['email']
        phone_no = request.json['phone_no']
        city = request.json['city']

        new_user = Users(name=name, email=email, phone_no=phone_no, city=city)
        room = Room(r_name='hello')
        new_user.rooms.append(room)
        db.session.add(new_user)
        db.session.commit()

        return jsonify({'message': 'successfully created user'})
```